# How to seamless build with CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

When I clone a project with a `configure` or even a `Makefile` I know that I can do `./configure && make` or just simply `make all && sudo make install`. But everytime I have a `CMakelists.txt` it makes my journey harder...

Usually I have to start by creating a new directory, then go into this directory, then launch `cmake` with an option I forgot perhaps `-G` or `-g`.. Then `Makefiles` or `LinuxMakefiles` or maybe `Linux Makefile` :

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -g "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
```

Usually in 99% of the time I get an error such as ... `file.h` No such file or directory. Today it is `#include <allegro5/color.h>` that can be installed with `allegro5` or perhaps `allegro-dev` or... let's try `liballegro5-dev` : `sudo apt-get install liballegro5-dev`... Yeah it works.

In this example I wanted to show how cumbersome it is to build a project with a `CmakeLists.txt`. Is there a way to make the experience more enjoyable : automatically list the dependencies, avoid creating a build folder, and remembering `Unix Makefiles`?

Comment: like autotools, you can build in sources, thus `cmake . && make`should work as well (even if this may not be a good idea, and maybe you woul dneed some prefix for install, but this is the same for autotools)

Comment: actually, it seems to be a problem of build dpendencies rather that build itself? Obviously you need to install you build deps before build, and this usually can be done thanks to you packet manager installing -dev (or -devel) packages, depending on the distro. Usually, projects indicate their dependencies in the readme file, maybe you forgot to have a look there?

Comment: Honestly you aren't making a fair comparison.  `./configure` fails all the time if you didn't install the proper build dependencies.  So you still get your 99% failure rate of missing `file.h` and having to guess what to install.  That isn't a CMake problem; that is a build dependency problem.  On Linux, the default generator is `Unix Makefiles` so in the simplest case you would have to do is `cmake . && cmake --build .`.  You only have to use `-G` if you don't like the default generator.   Or you can set your environment variable to select the defaults you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't call the build system directly. Instead, use it through cmake so that it will work regardless of which build system was configured:

```
# not this
#make
# do this
cmake --build .
```

> I forgot perhaps -G or -g.. Then Makefiles or LinuxMakefiles or maybe Linux Makefile

If you compile on Linux, then Unix Makefiles is the default. You can use the default simply by not specifying the argument:

```
cmake ..
```

When we use cmake to invoke the build system as in the first part of the answer, we don't even need to care which build system is being used.

If you want a custom default, you can use the environment variable [`CMAKE_GENERATOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/envvar/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html)

---

As for having multiple steps, although they tend to get stuck in one's brain through repeated use, there is no need to remember them off the top of your head. You can write them into a file, and that file can even be used as a shell script to execute them:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir --parents build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Technically you can do inline build, but I would not recommend that because separate directory makes it much easier to keep the build files out of version control, and out of the way of separate builds with different configurations.

Comment: The envrionment variables like the following can be used.  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/envvar/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html

Comment: @fdk1342 Thanks. Will edit.

Comment: FYI, there is also the -C option to run a script if you have a lot of favorites settings you'd like to use on every project.  I also saw a new Merge Request that expands upon storing default values in a json file to be used by the CMake tools.

Comment: Also `cmake -S . -B build` can also be used to create a separate build directory.